# Buttons with different colors and same styles

Tags: android, button, colors, styles

I'm working on an application that contains some buttons defined via layout.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/largebutton" >
</Button>
```

@drawable/largebutton looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient android:startColor="@color/menu_button_active_start" android:endColor="@color/menu_button_active_end" android:angle="270" />
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/largebutton_stroke" android:color="@color/menu_button_stroke" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/largebutton_radius" />
            <padding android:left="@dimen/largebutton_padding_leftright" android:top="@dimen/largebutton_padding_topbottom" android:right="@dimen/largebutton_padding_leftright" android:bottom="@dimen/largebutton_padding_topbottom" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient android:startColor="@color/menu_button_focused_start" android:endColor="@color/menu_button_focused_end" android:angle="270" />
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/largebutton_stroke" android:color="@color/menu_button_focused_stroke" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/largebutton_radius" />
            <padding android:left="@dimen/largebutton_padding_leftright" android:top="@dimen/largebutton_padding_topbottom" android:right="@dimen/largebutton_padding_leftright" android:bottom="@dimen/largebutton_padding_topbottom" />
        </shape>
    </item>
 .....
</selector>
```

All properties like padding, stroke, radius are the same, except gradient colors in different states. My problem is that my application has to have more styles. You can imagine it as you have list of colors and when you choose one application changes all colors to selected one. So if you have 20 colors, 20 different xmls isn't the right way.

Both startColor and endColor values for all android:states are downloaded from web and saved to DB and I don't know how many of them are there.

Is there any way to achieve this behavior? I've searched all forums and the most of answers were that it is imposible. I found one 'solution' overwriting colors.xml but it doesn't seems to be the best solution to me.

**So my question is, can I dynamically change color in colors.xml?** Something like this

```
List<Colors> colors = downloadColorsFromWeb();

Button b = new Button;
b.setDrawable(drawable.with(colors));
```

Thank you all in advance.

nosko.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably dynamically generate a drawable for each color you download. Check the GradientDrawable class. I think you can provide start/end colors during the initialization and set the stroke and corner radius properties after that. But you'll have to find out about the padding yourself. I am not sure.

After you create the drawable, you can use it in the button's `setBackgroundDrawable`

edit: probably setting the button's padding would do the trick

edit2: you can `setState` to the drawable but I am not sure how to set different background drawable for each state of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @stan0 for your reply, it helped a lot, especially **GradientDrawable class.**

I've wrote simple class that creates button and can set style depending on its state. Maybe it helps to someone :)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.Orientation;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * @author nosko
 *
 */
public class TabButton extends Button {

    private Context c;
    private GradientDrawable selected, focused, pressed, normal;

    public void setNormalState(GradientDrawable gd) {
        this.normal = gd;
    }

    public void setSelectedState(GradientDrawable gd) {
        this.selected = gd;
    }

    public void setFocusedState(GradientDrawable gd) {
        this.focused = gd;
    }

    public void setPressedState(GradientDrawable gd) {
        this.pressed = gd;
    }

    public TabButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        selected = pressed = focused = normal = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] { Color.WHITE, Color.DKGRAY });

        this.c          = context;
        this.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);        
    }


    /**
     * Change colors when button's state changes
     */
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {

        normal.setCornerRadius(8);
        normal.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor(c.getResources().getString(R.color.tab_button_border)));
        normal.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        this.setBackgroundDrawable(normal);

        if (isSelected()) {

            selected.setCornerRadius(8);
            selected.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor(c.getResources().getString(R.color.tab_button_border)));
            selected.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
            this.setBackgroundDrawable(selected);
        }

        if (isFocused()) {
            focused.setCornerRadius(8);
            focused.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor(c.getResources().getString(R.color.tab_button_border)));
            focused.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
            this.setBackgroundDrawable(focused);
        }

        if (isPressed()) {
            pressed.setCornerRadius(8);
            pressed.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor(c.getResources().getString(R.color.tab_button_border)));
            pressed.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
            this.setBackgroundDrawable(pressed);
        }
    }

}
```

and use it like this

```
TabButton b = new TabButton(context, null);

b.setNormalState(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] { Color.RED, Color.CYAN }));
b.setSelectedState(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] { Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE }));
b.setFocusedState(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] { Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN }));
b.setPressedState(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] { Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK }));
```